# Не работает всплывающая подсказка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Цель: всплывающая подсказка, которая ходит за мышкой. Подскажите, почему такая конструкция не работает:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').hover(
    function(e) {
      if ($(document).width() >= 641) {
        $thisModal = $(this).children('.modal-cursor').show();
      }
    },
    function(e) {
      if ($(document).width() >= 641) {
        $thisModal = $(this).children('.modal-cursor').hide();
      }
    });

  $('.modal-trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
    $(".modal-cursor").css('top', e.pageY + 10).css('left', e.pageX + 10);
  });

  $('.icon-container').on('click', function(event) {
    $this = $(this);

    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(document).width() <= 640) {

      $('.icon-container').not($(this)).find('.modal-cursor').hide(300);
      $('.icon-container').find('.text').removeClass('active');
      console.log("test")
      $this.find('.modal-cursor').toggle(300);
      $this.find('.text').toggleClass('active');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.home-icons {
  margin: 0 0 89px 0;
}

.home-icons h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
}

span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
}

h1.home {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #111111;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

.text-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: ' ';
}

.home-icons .icon-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.home-icons .icon-container .icon {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.home-icons .icon-container .icon img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.home-icons .icon-container .text {
  position: relative;
  color: #111111;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.modal-cursor {
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  color: #000000;
  display: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 30px 24px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 492px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  .modal-cursor h3 {
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  .modal-cursor p {
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-icons">
  <h1 class="home">Your end to end solutions provider</h1>
  <div class="text-center clearfix">


    <div class="icon-container">
      <div class="modal-trigger">
        <div class="icon">
          <img src="http://euroconveyor.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Проработка.png" alt="" class="loading">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <span>Feasibility</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-cursor">
          <h3>Feasibility</h3>
          <p>
            Design, installation and budget needs are assessed to provide you with accurate project overviews.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

---

Хочу попробовать такую конструкцию реализовать. это html код blurb-модуля темы wordpress Divi.
(Каша из разного кода, но не пойму как их раздельно добавлять)
http://jsfiddle.net/tsgchmbL/23/

```
    <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
                    <div class="et_pb_main_blurb_image"><span class="et_pb_image_wrap"><img src="http://euroconveyor.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Проработка.png" alt="" class="et-waypoint et_pb_animation_top et-animated"></span></div>
                    <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
                        <h4 class="et_pb_module_header">Проработка</h4>
                        <div class="et_pb_blurb_description">
                            <h4>Проработка</h4>
<p>С самого начала к Вашему запросу прикрепляется технический специалист, который уточняет все нюансы чтобы сделать для Вас самое выгодное предложение</p>
                        </div><!-- .et_pb_blurb_description -->
                    </div>
                </div>



 $(function() {
    $('.et_pb_blurb_description').hover(
      function(e) {

          $thisModal = $(this).children('.et_pb_blurb_description').show();
         });

      $('.et_pb_blurb_content').mousemove(function(e) {
          $(".et_pb_blurb_description").css('top', e.clientY + 10).css('left', e.clientX + 10);
        }
    );

    $('.et_pb_blurb').on('click', function(event) {
      $this = $(this);

      event.preventDefault();

    });

  });



  .et_pb_blurb_description
{
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.40);
    color: #000000;
    display: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 30px 24px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 492px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.et_pb_blurb_description h4{
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.et_pb_blurb_description p {
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Но она же работает, ты нажимаешь и появляется подсказка, которая следует за мышкой.

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили сообщение, первый раз пишу на в этом форуме

Answer (score 3):

Просто у тебя на jsfiddle jquery не подключен,только чистый js. Если подключишь jquery все заработает.

Comment: да, действительно!!! так просто, спасибо) но теперь проблема, когда встраиваю его в wordpress.. в jsfiddle всё работает, а на сайте(который на wordpress) окно не всплывает, не показывает, а увеличивается ползунок окна браузера, как-будто окно появляет под видимой областью экрана, внизу... https://ibb.co/bS0Ysy

Comment: Посмотрите что в консоли пишет,проследите за появлением html тегов и посмотрите их стили,возможно что-нибудь с позиционированием не то

Comment: да, вы правы, уходит слишком вправо и вниз.. вот скрин где в стилях это видно https://ibb.co/bZStQJ . в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Попробуйте js код заменить js'кодом отсюда: http://jsfiddle.net/tsgchmbL/18/

Comment: Ура! Почти нормально. сейчас он немного ниже, чем нужно показывает.. https://ibb.co/mPQYsy но по вертикали уже ровно))) буду смотреть, что вы изменили, и подкручивать ещё

Comment: Кажется, дело ещё и в html коде. у меня в стандартный шаблон темы wordpress вставлен модуль-кода, и уже в него вставлен html код) извращенство, грубо говоря, но как сделать иначе - не знаю

Comment: Если вам что-то подкручивать,то скорее всего стили на 15 строке,я изменил pageX и pageY на clientX и clientY. Если нужна еще помощь или нужно что-то сделать,могу дать свои контакты

Comment: хочу попробовать без костылек, а сделать собственными методами своей темы wordpress. я приложу код в ответе внизу, гляньте пожалуйста